# How to find element name or Id on a web page?

Tags: python

I am trying to login to twitter using selenium. How do i know the ID or name of the username and password fields and submit button?

So this is the username element:

```
<input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" 
name="session[username_or_email]" spellcheck="false" type="text" 
dir="auto" data-focusable="true" class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a 
r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-1inuy60 r- 
utggzx r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-641cr4 r-1dz5y72 r-1ttztb7 r-13qz1uu" 
value="">
```

I can find it with:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")
```

but not:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-1inuy60 r-utggzx r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-641cr4 r-1dz5y72 r-1ttztb7 r-13qz1uu")
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Open Chrome/Firefox, click F12 (Development mode). Click the Pointer Icon and click on the element (login input) you want to view. It will navigate to it in the Element view. Look at the ID/Class/Whatever you need

Comment: Right click on your webpage, and you can traverse through the html code and find them.

Comment: Thanks i can find my element by name but not class name?